# Border inside a cell

Tags: html-table, hover, border, cell

How do I set CSS to show borders inside td rather than outside on hover. Normally when I hover a cell and I have set border in hover style, the table rows moves by width of hover border. I want it to show inside thus no moving. (For example cell is 10px width and I add 2px border I still want it be 10 pixel width but with 2px border on each side, thus 6px left for consent.)

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/reg4f/

Here's my HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
 <td>
   <a>po</a>
 </td>
 <td>
   <a>út</a>
 </td>
</tr>
<table>
```

and CSS

```
table {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border: solid black 1px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td, table tr {
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align:middle; 
}
td:hover{
  background-color: #E5F3FB;
  border: solid 4px #70C0E7;
  border-style: inset;
}
td a {
  display:block;width:100%;height:100%;margin:0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a white or transparent border to the cell, when it's not :hover and override this white border by your colored one when it's :hover. So you have no moving.

```
td {
 border: solid 4px rgba(0,0,0,0);   
}
```

Here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/G6w9P/

Comment: I tried this but transparent border overwrites the hover's one. In fact only bottom and right are displayed and left and top are hidden by transparent border. Anyway its not moving this way.

Comment: Really? In the given jsFiddle example I don't have a hidden left & top border. It's just another color than the bottom & right one because the hover border style is set to "inset", that means the Browser will change the color of the left&top border to create a 3D feeling. Try this one, maybe that's what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/qw6vT/

Comment: Ok got it. I had to remove border collapse, because it collapses table border and td border, thus moving rows.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest adding padding to not hover of the same width as the border on hover.  On hover remove the padding and add the border.

Something like:

```
td{
    padding:2,2,2,2;
    border:none;
}

td:hover{
    padding:0,0,0,0;
    border:solid 2px red;
}
```

Cheers
-L